# How to move a camera around an object

Tags: camera

I want to move the camera by 15 degrees based on the x, y, and z axes like in the picture, what should I do?
The camera and the object are connected by empty, and I want to move around the hemisphere while keeping the distance between them constant.
After moving each one, I'm going to record the first push-up, but I'm not sure what to do.[image]

Comment: first of all you should state a very clear question so that there is no misunderstanding. What do you mean with "connected"-> parented? if yes, just create another empty in 0,0,0 -> parent your cam to that empty, Then on frame 0 insert rotation keyframe for that empty, on maybe frame 10, set z rotation to 15, keyframe, ready.

Comment: You're almost there already. Parent you camera to the empty with Keep Transform. You can then rotate the **empty** in any direction and the camera will follow it. [Here](https://youtu.be/Y9odlxWL_pI) is a quick YT video showing how to do it.

Comment: Thanks to you, I solved it. Thank you.